# Catching staleobjectexception

Tags: hibernate

how to catch `staleobjectexception`?

In my application I am trying to flush a transaction and tries to call same method in `dao` layer twice in a span of half a second. I am getting `staleobjectexception`. I am unable to catch above mentioned exception. Please advise

Comment: You catch that exception like any other in Java (is this Java?): with a try/catch. You'll probably need to provide more details for any better answers.

Comment: yeah its in java, exception is thrown during run time, even if i have try catch clause with staleobjectexception, i cant catch the exception, moreover in my server logs i can see exception being logged as                         org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#xxxxxxxxx] at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2335) (EntityUpdateAction.java:115)at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always catch an exception. The only reason you wouldn't be able to catch it is if it's not thrown inside your try/catch. You're probably putting the try/catch around some persistence operations, expecting it to be thrown there, when persistence exceptions don't actually happen until the transaction is committed. You'll need to find where the transaction commits and make sure to put your try/catch around that. You can use the exception stacktrac to trace back to where it's thrown from.

Comment: i tried keeping try catch around the place where I am trying to flush the transaction, but i cant catch this particular exception. I guess exception is swallowed and logged in hibernate framework instead of caller catching the exception

Comment: I've never seen Hibernate swallow a stale state exception of any kind, and I don't believe it logs them normally, either. You might have something doing exception translation and/or something else catching and logging it that you're not aware of. The simplest solution would be to hook up a debugger and add an exception breakpoint on the exact exception you're seeing.